# Converting Oracle Timestamp datatype string to Java Date

Tags: java, oracle, date

I have a timestamp field of Oracle in Java String

String strDate = "24.12.12 03:30:00,000"; //Timestamp field of Oracle

I need to convert it to Java.util.Date.

Please tell me a way to do this.

**Note: I don't have first two digits for the year, how can java understand that this is year 1912 or 2012 and so on.**

Comment: Are you fetching this String from a java.sql.ResultSet? If so, why not call ResultSet.getTimestamp() instead of ResultSet.getString()?

Comment: The right answer is already posted, but you could also select via `to_timestamp()` to Oracle itself and have JDBC convert it for you, but `SimpleDateFormat` is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class you want is [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  You'll create a pattern that matches your expected input, and parse it.  Here's an example, though it may be incorrect in some places (I used 0-23 hour, maybe you want 1-24, etc.)

```
String strDate = "24.12.12 03:30:00,000";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss,SSS");
Date date = sdf.parse(strDate);
```

Regarding your 1912 vs 2012 problem, Java will make some assumptions when there are only 2 digits.  Specifically:

> For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y" or "yy"),
>   SimpleDateFormat must interpret the abbreviated year relative to some
>   century. It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before
>   and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat instance is created.